# Shared life of Java objects with = operator

Tags: java

`Class1` has an attribute of type `Class2`, named `pippo`:

```
public class Class1{

           private Class2 pippo; //an attributo of Class1

           .....

           public Class2 getPippo()
           { return this.pippo;}
}
```

now consider a well formed instance of `Class1` named `pluto` and consider the following flow:

```
Class2 obj=pluto.getPippo();

// I apply some modification on obj
```

now the instance `obj` of type `Class1` is clearly modified.

**Question:** do such modifications apply also to `Class1 pluto` object, meaning that do `obj` and `pluto.pippo` have the same "life" due to `=` operator?

Comment: what do you mean by the same "life" ?

Comment: Whatever update I do on `obj`, is it actually done on `pluto.pippo`?

Comment: Mind that `obj = jupiter.getPippo()` won't affect the "pippo" of `pluto`.

Comment: @Leonardo: *"Whatever update I do on obj, is it actually done on pluto.pippo?"* It's done on the object that `pippo` *refers to*, yes. `pippo`, the instance field, is not changed. The state of the object is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Question: do such modifications apply also to `Class1 pluto` object,

The answer to that question is: The question, itself, is a misunderstanding. :-)

`pippo` and `obj` are variables that both *refer to* (point to) the **same** object. So there aren't two objects which are somehow linked, there is *one* object that you have two references (pointers) to.

So naturally, if you change the state of that object via one reference, that updated state is visible through the other reference.

Let's take the simpler example:

```
Thingy t1 = new Thingy();
```

That gives us this in memory:

```
+---------------+      +-----------------+
| t1 (variable) |----->| Thingy instance |
+---------------+      +-----------------+
                       | field: value    |
                       | ...             |
                       +-----------------+
```

Then if we do:

```
Thingy t2 = t1;
```

we have:

```
+---------------+
| t1 (variable) |--+
+---------------+  |
                   |
                   |   +-----------------+
                   +-->| Thingy instance |
                   |   +-----------------+
                   |   | field: value    |
+---------------+  |   | ...             |
| t2 (variable) |--+   +-----------------+
+---------------+
```

The situation with `pippo` and `obj` is exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

A great understanding of the heap is needed, when you use the keyword `new` to create an object. This object will be created on the Heap, if you use the = sign to assign an object to equal another object, you will actually reference the same object on the Heap.

```
Person person = new Person();
Person clone = person;

person.FirstName = "John";
clone.LastName = "Doe";
```

This code will only create one Object on the Heap and the first name will be John and last name Doe. I you want to create of duplicate of your object, you will need to look into `.clone()` method.

And to the question, if you do something similiar to `obj1 = obj2;` then yes.